# Could light be frozen?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, absolute-units

If a beam of light in a vacuum was instantaneously changed in temperature (along with the surrounding area) to absolute zero, would the beam freeze in place or just be snuffed out? If it froze in place, could it snap somehow (I know that any movement that would cause this would increase the temperature above absolute zero, but if that somehow weren't the case). Just a silly question.

Answer (score 0):

Neither a beam of light or a vacuum can have a temperature. It’s other things that heat up. Light does travel through deep space where it is close to absolute zero.

Comment: [Black body radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation) (which somewhat resembles a beam of light) most assuredly has a temperature.

Comment: @PeterShor photons do not have a temperature themselves they only pass on the energy.

Comment: @PeterShor, black body radiation has a characteristic spectrum that varies depending on the temperature of the source that emitted it.  That doesn't mean that the radiation itself has a temperature or that it can be "cooled" (or heated) as it travels

Comment: @The Photon: Black body radiation having a characteristic spectrum of temperature $T$ acts ***exactly like*** a heat bath at a temperature $T$. If it is in contact with anything warmer than $T$, that thing will cool off, and if it is in contact with anything colder than $T$, that thing will warm up. But I suppose if you insist that photons cannot actually be said to have a temperature, there is nothing I can say that will convince you.

Comment: @PeterShor, does the radiation "cool down" when it comes in contact with a cooler object (say a semi-transparent one for the question to even make sense)?